# there is an error while sending request gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-sheets, gspread

while sending data to google spreadsheet api returns me error:
`b'{"success":false,"message":"initConnectionError","error":"Error: error sending request for url (http://vo4.co/ip-info): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)"}'`

my program just fills cells with text, then recolors cells

i dont try anything 'cause i dont know what is the problem
before it i set time.sleep when api reachs the limit

Comment: Can you provide your current script for correctly replicating your current issue of `b'{"success":false,"message":"initConnectionError","error":"Error: error sending request for url (http://vo4.co/ip-info): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (os error 10061)"}'`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.